# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT extremely slow with multiple constraints but fast with one

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below runs extremely fast (Less than 1 second) with one ID

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CODE SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM TABLE
WHERE TYPE='A' AND ID IN ( 1 )
GROUP BY ID;
```

But extremely slow (Over 10 seconds) when run with more than one ID

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CODE SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM TABLE
WHERE TYPE='A' AND ID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY ID;
```

I think it's because MySQL tries to perform the GROUP_CONCAT on all IDs first, then compares it with the IN constraint. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both queries?

Comment: Also show your indexes. I'm going to guess that the first is using index merge optimization and second is scanning rows.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your help. I have rephrased the question because of a query mistake I made.

Comment: The only difference between the two EXPLAINS: "Extra: Using filesort" only shows up on the second. The first also uses index ID, the second uses index CODE.

Comment: I solved it! Thanks for the help guys. The second query is using the wrong index (CODE_IDX), after I specified USE INDEX ID_IDX the query is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

The `Boolean` logic of the first query is not the same as the second query.

```
First  = TYPE = ('A' AND ID = 1) OR ID = 2

Second = TYPE = 'A' AND (ID = 1 OR ID = 2)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: If what you're saying is true, then only the second query is correct. But in this case, both of them return the same correct result.

EDIT: I think you might be right. I just tried putting the OR statements in parenthesis (), but the query still runs much faster than the IN version.

Comment: @roller3d, it's correct. There is a [precedence for AND and OR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html). Check your data.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I have fixed the logic mistake and rephrased the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. (Thanks to you guys leading the way.)

MySQL was using the wrong TYPE_IDX index in the second query with multiple IDs. The query is now much faster when I specify to use ID_IDX:

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(CODE SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM TABLE
USE INDEX (ID_IDX)
WHERE TYPE='A' AND ID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY ID;
```